# Change the UILabel when a static variable changes

Tags: swift, static, tableview, uilabel, stepper

I have a `CartItem` struct where I store the items that I show in a `UITableView` My `UITableView` is in `CartViewController`. I use `custom cell` for my `table view`. Here is my `custom cell`:

```
class CartItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productTotalPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

var cellIndex: Int?

var product: CartItem?{
    didSet{
    
    // change the cell in table view when first 
    // initialized and when stepper value is changed 
    .
    .
    .
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    CartItem.cartItems[self.cellIndex!].number = Int(sender.value)
    self.product?.number = CartItem.cartItems[self.cellIndex!].number
    }
}
```

---

In `CartViewController` I have `totalPrice UILabel` which gets its value from `CartItem.totalPrice` static variable. `CartItem.totalPrice`'s value is calculated and changed every time `UIStepper` in my `UITableViewCell` is clicked. Here is the summary of  `CartViewController`

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var cartLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalPrice: UILabel!

var items = CartItem.cartItems

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CartItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
    self.totalPrice.text = String(Int(CartItem.totalPrice))
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}


extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CartItemCell
    
    cell.product = items[indexPath.item]
    cell.cellIndex = indexPath.item
    return cell
}

}
```

---

---

---

## I want `totalPrice` label in the `CartViewController` changed every time `CartItem.totalPrice` is changed. I change the value of the `CartItem.totalPrice` in my `CartItemCell`

---

---

### Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegate or closures to update value from tableviewcell to viewController

```
Protocol CartItemProtocol: AnyObject{
    func valueUpdated() 
}

class CartItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productTotalPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
weak var delegate: CartItemProtocol?


override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
// Initialization code
}

var cellIndex: Int?

var product: CartItem?{
    didSet{

    // change the cell in table view when first 
    // initialized and when stepper value is changed 
    .
    .
    .
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    CartItem.cartItems[self.cellIndex!].number = Int(sender.value)
    self.product?.number = CartItem.cartItems[self.cellIndex!].number
   self.delegate.valueUpdated()
    }
}
```

And set delegate in cellforRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CartItemCell

    cell.product = items[indexPath.item]
    cell.cellIndex = indexPath.item
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

And Update label in delegate conformation

```
extension CartViewController:CartItemProtocl{
    self.totalPrice.text = String(Int(CartItem.totalPrice))
}
```